# How can I pass input type value or id from one jsp to another jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I want to book a online room at paticular date and time. For that I created one jsp page(entry.jsp) where I am selecting date(datepicker) and time.
And in 2nd jsp page(checkRoom.jsp) I came to know which room is available.

So if I select available room then it will go to 3rd jsp page(roomDetails.jsp)
where I am displaying date and time along with giving one input duration(from scrollable), so that I can calculate price of available room.

My question is how can I pass date id(#date from entry.jsp) to roomDetails.jsp because i have a method like `calculatePrice('#date','#duration')` in roomDetails m using postMessage to display price.

In roomDeatils.jsp I have written like this method.

```
$(document).ready(function() {$("#date, #tickets_duration").change(calculateTotalPrice);  function calculateTotalPrice() {
    if ($("#tickets_duration").val() != "" && $("#date").val() != "") {
        if (window.Worker) {
            // create web worker
            var blob = new Blob(
                    [ document.querySelector("#worker").textContent ], {
                        type : 'text/javascript'
                    });
            var worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));

            worker.onmessage = function(event) {
                $("#total_price").html(event.data);
            }
            worker.onerror = function(errorObject) {
                $("#total_price").html("Error: " + errorObject.message);
            }
            var date = new Date($('#date').val());
                        alert(date);
            // get day
            var day = date.getDay();

            // get number of booked shows

            // send JSON data to worker                     
            var jsonData = {
                'day' : day,
                'tickets_duration' : Number($("#tickets_duration").val())
            };
            worker.postMessage(jsonData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsp:forward action tag can help you with this.

Just send in the variable and its value from one jsp to the other

Comment: #thanks. Can you give me a sample code.so that i can understand in a better way.

Comment: In the jsp page that you are currently in, add the following tags.

**<jsp:forward page="relativeURL>  
       <jsp:param name="parametername" value="parametervalue" />  
</jsp:forward>**

relativeURL will be the page that you are trying to forward to and the parametername and the value are what you need to pass.

User _request.getParameter("parametername")_ to get the parameter in the forwarded page

Comment: i am selecting date from datepicker in entry.jsp page,,then how can i pass date as value to roomDetails.jsp..????

Comment: Say you save the date from the datepicker in a variable dateFromDatePicker

**<jsp:forward page="entry.jsp> 
<jsp:param name="datename" value= dateFromDatePicker/>
 </jsp:forward>**

In the entry.jsp page, you can retrieve it using **request.getParameter("datename")**